# Calculate two/four corners (East,North,West,South) from the list of polygons

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I want to identify the four/two corner of any city/state/country or area.
Let's suppose that I want to identify the corners zipcode for the USA.
I have the list of the zip-code with their ctrx(longitude) & ctry(latitude). and I have tried the:
-- first corner

```
SELECT * FROM optimization_test.account order by latitude(ctry);
```

-- second corner

```
SELECT * FROM optimization_test.account order by longitude(ctrx) desc;
```

But it's not working with FULL USA. Please guide me to identify the corner zipcodes for USA/any group of zipcodes.

Comment: what do you mean  with  "But it's not working with FULL USA."   show us a valid data sample your actual result and your expected  result

Comment: @scaisedge- I have data something like below...  Zipcode   ctrx(longitude) ctry(latitude). Let's take a example - I have all the zipcode of Alaska with centroid values. Now I want to identify the East/West/North/South corners zipcode.

Comment: The top/bottom most point is not necessarily a corner point.

Comment: @JGH- please suggest any solution. I'll really appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

You could try select the max and the min for latidtude and longintude .. these values should be the max rectangle for all the crty

```
 SELECT  max(ctry_latitude) NORTH
  ,  max(ctry_longitude) EAST
  ,  min(ctry_latitude) SOUTH
  ,  min(ctry_longitude)   WEST  
 FROM optimization_test.account
```